# How to know last tab id in activity group?

Tags: android, tabs, tabactivity

i have implemented activity group in tab host.having 4 activity group.in every first activity of each activity group i have a back button.i am facing one problem.let's assume i am having 4activity group say A,B,C,D.now when application launch,on that time activity group A will be there,when i swith from A->B on than from B->C,now i am in activity group called C.now when i click back button of activity group of a C.on that time current tab of tab host should be prevous tab host from which i have navigated to C.is there any standard method to do that or we need to put as per our logic?

Thanks

Comment: i think you should implement Interface this is the standard way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard way to do that, but then again, anything is possible with some logic! I had a similar problem in my earlier app. I solved it by maintaining a stack of last opened tabs, and then overriding the back button pressed to remove the tabs from the stack. Some sample code is given below.
Initialize the variables as follows

```
tabIdStack = new Stack<Integer>();
openedTab = 0;
```

and then override the `onTabChanged()`

```
@Override
    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        if (!backButtonPressed) {
            if (tabIdStack != null) {
                if (tabIdStack.size() == noOfTabs)
                    tabIdStack.remove(0);
                tabIdStack.push(openedTab);
                openedTab = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
            }
        }
        backButtonPressed = false;
```

and then you should also override the `onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        backButtonPressed = true;
        if (tabIdStack.size() == 0)
            this.finish();
        else {
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(tabIdStack.get(tabIdStack.size() - 1));
            tabIdStack.remove(tabIdStack.size() - 1);
        }       
    }
```